# Mirah 'Unrecognized flag: --java'

Tags: jruby, mirah

mirah --version:

`Mirah v0.1.3`

jruby --version:

`jruby 1.7.13 (1.9.3p392) 2014-06-24 43f133c on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Serve
r VM 1.7.0_67-b01 [Windows 8.1-amd64]`

From Mirah.org, on the howto page, I should be able to use `mirahc --java <SOME_FILE>` to acquire java files from my source. However, I get `Unrecognized flag: --java`. I checked `--help` on both `mirah` and `mirahc`, and neither have a `--java` flag listed.

Is this no longer a feature?

Coming from a strong background of Java and Ruby, I was hoping to learn by trying things and viewing the compiled Java source.

**EDIT:**

I just checked here, [github](https://github.com/mirah/mirah/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=--java).

Apparently it was removed for some reason. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this is a deprecated feature (for reasons I have not discovered).

However, after some hunting, this same functionality can be simulated by use of a Java decompiler after having compiled with `mirahc`.

[Jad](http://varaneckas.com/jad/) turned out to be perfect for the job, generating perfect Java source to illuminate what Mirah is doing behind the scenes.